# A generator of a different form than the one given by the primitive element theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I want to find generators of the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{2})$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Using the primitive element theorem (see [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~greenber/MATH404-PrimElem.pdf)), I get $pi+q\sqrt[3]{2}$, for every nonzero rational $p,q$, is a generator for the field extension (i.e. $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ where $\gamma=pi+q\sqrt[3]{2}$ for any nonzero rational $p,q$).

My question is, are these the only possibilities for the generator, or can there be a generator of different form? How can I show this?

Comment: is it equivalent to $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{4})$ ? as $\sqrt[3]{4}*\sqrt[3]{4}=2*\sqrt[3]{2}$

Comment: @ZangMingJie Yes it is the same. So one can see that $pi+q\sqrt[3]{4}$ are also generators of the field, and those are different from the elements listed in the question.

Comment: How do you know $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{2})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{4})$? $\supseteq$ holds because $\sqrt[3]{4}=(\sqrt[3]{2})^2$ but for $\subseteq$, how do you show?

Comment: As $\sqrt[3]{2} = (\frac{1}{2}i)(-i)(\sqrt[3]{4})^2$, all factors belong to $\mathbb Q(i, \sqrt[3]{4})$, and field is closed to multiplication.

Comment: Why does it work for all nonzero rational $p,q$ ? Doesn't the proof of the primitive element theorem say that for a nonzero choice of $p$, $\mathbb{Q}(i, 2^{1/3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\gamma)$ for all but finitely many choices of q ?